Interactive Server Side Streaming on Client side project in .Net 8 Blazor
With the 2 projects that is split out in .Net 8 Blazor Web App, if I set a component on the Client project as server side will I be able to call the database, save files to the servers disk. Or are you still limited to web assembly functionality since it resides in the Client project. If so how do you call a component in the server project in a component inside of the Client project?
